# Issue trying to configure Qt Creator with OpenCV

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qt-creator

I'm trying to configure Qt Creator (Qt 5.4.1) with OpenCV 2.4.10. I've followed the steps on this page: https://zahidhasan.wordpress.com/2014/08/19/qt-5-3-1-64-bit-mingw-windows/

I followed all steps to the letter except this:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv-mingw\install\include
LIBS += -L”C:/opencv-mingw/install/x64/mingw/bin”
LIBS += -lopencv_core249 -lopencv_highgui249 -lopencv_imgproc249
```

I changed it to

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv-mingw\install\include
LIBS += -L”C:/opencv-mingw/install/x64/mingw/bin”
LIBS += -lopencv_core2410 -lopencv_highgui2410 -lopencv_imgproc2410
```

(Since the OpenCV version in question happens to be 2.4.10 instead of 2.4.9)

Yet when I try to build the project I get the following errors:

```
:-1: error: cannot find -lopencv_core2410
:-1: error: cannot find -lopencv_highgui2410
:-1: error: cannot find -lopencv_imgproc2410
```

Apparently, Qt Creator can't find the libraries for some reason. I haven't tried to add any lines of code to the project as of yet, I was first trying to make sure the project would build, but it won't. I also will note that I don't have  experience with either Qt Creator or OpenCV, so any help on solving this issue is appreciated!

Comment: Did you build libraries successfully? Can you open C:/opencv-mingw/install/x64/mingw/bin folder and check these three libraries are there?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thanks for the response. They were there, yes, but I solved the issue by importing the binaries generated by CMake. the directory was C:/opencv-mingw/bin.

Comment: will you post your solution as answer to help other people who may encounter the same problem?

Comment: Ok, like I said ,I resolved the issue by importing the binaries from C:/opencv-mingw/bin instead of C:/opencv-mingw/install/x64/mingw/bin. I don't know why this worked, but I've had no further issues using OpenCV after this

Comment: on stackoverflow you should post solution as answer, not as comment. You can accept your own answer if it solves your problem.