# Qt Creator - OpenCV - undefined reference/can't find libraries

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

Windows 7  
Qt 5.4.0 
OpenCV 2.4.10 
Mingw 4.9.1 
 
I'm trying to create a simple Hello World app, to test if Qt is working with OpenCV. Besides the stuff created by default, the code is

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
(...)
cv::Mat image= cv::imread("pic.jpg");
cv::namedWindow("Test picture");
cv::imshow("Test picture", image);
cv::waitKey(1000);
(...)
```

However, I'm having trouble linking libraries. At first I've set the paths to *.dll.a files manually

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv/my_build/install/include
INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv/my_build/install/include/opencv
INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv/my_build/install/include/opencv2
LIBS += -LC:/opencv/my_build/install/x86/mingw/lib \
        -llibopencv_core2410 \
        -llibopencv_highgui2410
etc etc
```

But then I'd get a `cannot find -llibopencv_<lib>2410` error. I've even used Qt Creator's "Add library" function (Projects -> rightclick -> add library), the result is the same. That error only goes away if I change `-llibopencv_<lib>2410` to `-opencv_<lib>2410`. Which from my understanding is weird, as the "l" argument is missing. 
Even though that error goes away, a bunch of others replace it, as I get `undefined reference to cv::EVERYTHING` error. I've looked around, found solutions to either problem, but solving one leads to the other and vice versa.

I'm fairly sure the OpenCV build is not at fault - I've already completed a pretty big console-ish app using it with Code::Blocks.

My current *.pro file :

```
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = OpenCVTest
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv/my_build/install/include

win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../OpenCV/my_build/install/x86/mingw/lib/ -llibopencv_core2410

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../OpenCV/my_build/install/x86/mingw
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../OpenCV/my_build/install/x86/mingw

win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../OpenCV/my_build/install/x86/mingw/lib/ -llibopencv_highgui2410

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../OpenCV/my_build/install/x86/mingw
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../OpenCV/my_build/install/x86/mingw
```

How to correctly link the OpenCV libraries to Qt Creator? Am I missing something?

edit: I've rebuilt the whole damn thing and it still doesn't work. God damn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, I have little idea of what went wrong. I've edited the environment PATH variable, twice, to include the OpenCV build. Maybe I've made a typo the first time. It now looks like this:

```
C:\MinGW\bin;C:\OpenCV\my_build\install\x86\mingw\bin;C:\Qt\5.4.0\5.4\mingw491_32\bin;
```

My *.pro file also looks different.

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = OpenCVTest
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += C:/OpenCV/qtbuild//install/include
LIBS += "C:/OpenCV/qtbuild/install/x86\mingw/lib/*.a"

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

I've change `+=gui` to `-=gui` and added `CONFIG -= app_bundle`. The INCLUDE and LIBS paths are also different now - I won't be changing them out of an irrational fear something will go horribly wrong again.

And lastly, I've simply removed the previous project and made a new one. Maybe something else got corrupted?

Anyway, it works now, after doing these things.

Answer (score 1):

When specifying library, you need to exclude the 'lib' part:

```
LIBS += -LC:/opencv/my_build/install/x86/mingw/lib \
    -lopencv_core2410 \
    -lopencv_highgui2410
```

Comment: I get " cannot find -lopencv_<lib>2410" errors anyway

Comment: There is suggestion to use different directory for `-L` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29870484/issue-trying-to-configure-qt-creator-with-opencv